# How do i fill the session_id from BotTelemetryClient.TrackEvent() Microsoft.Bot.Builder

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights

When tracking events in a bot i use application insights to do transcript logging and logging in general.
However i don't get a session_id/conversation id when tracking events.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#add-custom-logging-to-your-bot) information i should always get a session_id and userId.

Session_id empty in customEvent https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaYWQ.jpg
I have based my project on the virtual assistent template for logging.
For logging i use the telemetryloggermiddleware and transcriptloggermiddleware

I expect there would be a session_id and userid, but instead i receive an empty userid and session_id

These are my package references:

- "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.9.1"
- "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.6.1"
- "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.4.4"
- "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.ApplicationInsights.Core"
  Version="4.4.4"
- "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core" Version="4.4.4"

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue @NickVandenberghe?

Comment: @Zeryth, yes i'm still figuring out a way to get the userId From the ITurnContext in the TelemetryInitializer

Answer (score 0):

If auto-collection does not populate the necessary property, you can add the value of the required property via [Telemetry Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer):

```
  public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Session.Id = "ConversationIdYouObtainedFromSomeAPI";
    }
  }
```

Comment: @NickVandenberghe Have you got it working ? I'm facing same issue.